# How to set cookie in fetch (for POST API) on IP based URL

Tags: javascript, rest, cookies, reactjs, fetch

I am using fetch for REST API in reactJS, and passing cookie using

```
 credentials: "include"
```

But its not working for (**IP based url). here is my Response Header configuration.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token, X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:8080
Content-Length:93
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 24 Jul 2016 20:29:48 GMT
```

**  my local ip is 192.168.1.4 when i am doing POST request,  cookie  not sending to server

```
 fetch('http://192.168.1.4:9000/test', {
        credentials: "include",
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'cors',   
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
           "username":"abd",
           "passwd":"Changemes1"
        })
```

here is request Header for local ip (192.168.1.4)

```
accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,hi;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:115
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host:192.168.1.4:9000
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
```

BUT WHEN IM USING localhost instead of my local ip (192.168.1.4) THEN BROWSER SENDING COOKIE PERFECTLY

```
 fetch('http://localhost:9000/test', {
            credentials: "include",
            method: 'post',
            mode: 'cors',   
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
               "username":"abd",
               "passwd":"Changemes1"
            })
```

SEE HERE (request header, **Cookie:Token=John Doe** present)-

```
accept:application/json
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,hi;q=0.4,ru;q=0.2
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:115
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:Token=John Doe
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
```

**What is Problem with IP based url Please suggest me.**

Comment: Did you ever set the cookie for the IP-based URL?

Comment: Yes, i set cookie for both URL